# What is the correct way to pass an RDS DatabaseCluster from one stack to another?

Tags: aws-cdk

I have a db Stack that is then passed to another Stack:

```js
class DbStack extends cdk.Stack {
  public dbSocket: string;
  public dbReadSocket: string;
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props: { vpc: ec2.Vpc }) {
    super(scope, id);
    const { vpc } = props;
    const db = new DatabaseCluster(this, "Database", {
      engine: rds.DatabaseClusterEngine.AuroraPostgresql,
      ....
    });
    this.dbSocket = db.clusterEndpoint.socketAddress;
    this.dbReadSocket = db.clusterReadEndpoint.socketAddress;
  }
}

const dbStack = new DbStack(app, "db", { vpc });

new MyStack(app, "mystack", {
  vpc,
  dbSocket: dbStack.dbSocket,
  dbReadSocket: dbStack.dbReadSocket,
}
```

In the other stack, I pass those sockets to ECS environment variables:

```js
export class PpfStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props: MyStackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const { vpc, dbSocket, dbReadSocket } = props;

    new MyService(this, "svc", {
      vpc,
      ...
      environment: {
        NODE_ENV: "production",
        DATABASE_RO_SOCKET: dbReadSocket,
        DATABASE_RW_SOCKET: dbSocket,
      },
    });
```

Unfortunately the environment variables end up coming out as:

```
db-databasec2aad89b-1t1yxzplxjsvu.cluster-cppalohfw5gz.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com:{IndirectPort}
```

**UPDATE** This looks like a bug: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cdk/issues/2711

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the easiest and most straight-forward way, would be to use an output. In your first stack, you add an output (let's assume you defined 'databaseOutput: CfnOutput;' on the class level of your stack):

```js
this.databaseOutput = new CfnOutput(this, 'DatabaseOutput', {
    export: 'db-stack-database-cluster',
    value: db.clusterIdentifier
});
```

Then, in the other Stack you can call the 'fromDatabaseClusterAttributes' import method:

```js
const db = DatabaseCluster.fromDatabaseClusterAttributes(this, 'ImportedDatabase', {
    clusterIdentifier: Fn.importValue('db-stack-database-cluster');
});
```

Then DatabaseCluster object is initialized accordingly and you can access all its properties and then pass them to your environment variables.

If the cluster identifier is not unique (sorry, I'm not that deeply involved with RDS), you can define more outputs and use them to expose more values. Then, you can use all of them during the 'fromDatabaseClusterAttributes' call.

Have a look at https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cdk/blob/b86404116cb8f3666e86d6c40e0a7f1a36b04fbb/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-rds/lib/cluster-ref.ts#L46 to see which properties you can use.